# how to use racket match to parse from the top of a stack - turn off greedy '...'

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

I have a parser and am looking for patterns off the top of the stack.

Say for example, that '3' is the separator and I want the next item off the top of the stack no 
matter what that item happens to be, though in this example the items happens to be '(1 2 7). I do this:

```
racket@match.rkt> (match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) [(list i ... 3 s ...) (list i s)])
'((1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7) (8))

(match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) [(list (? number? i) ... 3 s ...) (list i s)])
'((1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7) (8))
```

I had expected to see '((1 2 7) (4 5 3 6 7 3 8)), but because '...' is 'greedy' I get nearly the entire stack back instead - not what I wanted.

Is there a simple way to pull patterned items from the top of a stack?

Here is a second example using more familiar xml like 'tags' instead of numbers.  Here we have a file which is a stream of tags, and we want the first section from the file, so:

```
racket> (match 
    (list "<apple>" "apple-stuff" "</apple>" 
          "<orange>" "orange-stuff" "</orange>" 
          "<apple>" "more-apple-stuff" "</apple>" 
    )
  [(list  "<apple>" a-stuff ... "</apple>" etc ...)
    a-stuff
  ]
)
```

So one might expect a-stuff to be "apple-stuff", but in fact a-stuff is bound to entire rest of the file:

```
  a-stuff>
    '("apple-stuff"
      "</apple>"
      "<orange>"
      "orange-stuff"
      "</orange>"
      "<apple>"
      "more-apple-stuff")
```

These are just simple string matches, if instead we have structured tokens, the match rules will get much more involved and the '...' meaning 'match til end and step back' will have more subtle differences from what many people expect, which is 'match forward until next pattern match'.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to change i ... to match non-3s.

If you are searching for a fixed datum like 3, then you can do this:

```
(match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) 
   [(list (and i (not 3)) ... 3 s ...) (list i s)])
```

If you need to search for a non-datum, then you can use:

```
(let ([stop-value 3])
   (match '(1 2 7 3 4 5 3 6 7 3 8) 
     [(list (and i (not (== stop-value))) ... stop-value s ...) (list i s)]))
```

Comment: The first one yields `match: incorrect use of ... in pattern in: ...`.

Comment: I accidently pasted the wrong expression from the repl. An edit has fixed it.

Comment: Because of this solution I wrote "simple way to do it".  This solution requires that I match both the pattern I'm looking for, and the next pattern  - in every single rule.  The stop pattern now must be consistent with the next pattern, and all edits of the next pattern in the list now require also updating every rule to be matched. This is not a reasonable solution as it is more work and higher maintenance then writing a routine does a non-greedy match.

Comment: (This is meant to be simple to understand example of the problem of being forced to do greedy matching. You might imagine the 3 to be a semicolon token with structure or a number of other cases. The solution proposed here is only practical for simple cases, what I would like is a more general solution for more complex patterns as one sees in a parser and would like to match from the top of a stack. Of course.)

Comment: The ... in match is always greedy, so I don't think there is match-based solution. I suggest you write a function instead.

Comment: user244488: @soegaard took the the time to give a good answer to your original question -- before you edited it. Maybe you could accept his answer, and open a fresh question?

Comment: Now two comments above I explained why this answer is not practical, and responding that someone else's time is more improtant or saying I should except it because it is a "good answer" is not helpful to understanding the topic.  ... I also spent a lot of time reducing this issue to a simple comprehensible form, as believe me the real code would be too much to deal with here.  I wouldn't be surprised if this issue is not at the heart of many match bugs other than the one I've happened on here, where things get skipped over.

Comment: The recent edit literally just adds another example of the exact same form at the bottom of the original post.  You can see it is the same form by substituting "<apple>" with the number 1, etc. I added the example as some people didn't see the symbolic nature of the match and instead looked at it like a math problem.  I think it is helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/23567/soegaard If you want to put your comment above,  Ï don't think there is a match-based ... I will accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `...` in match is always greedy, so I don't think there is match-based solution. I suggest you write a function instead.